# adding Waze button to mobile site

Tags: css, html, mobile

I need to add Waze button to mobile site, I copy the code from other site but when I click from my site it doesnt build a track on waze, and if I click from the other site it builds a track.

the url of the other site is:
http://go5.co.il/m/location.php?id=10707

the url of my site is:
http://easy-time.info/mobile/admin/pg6-admin.php

the code I copied is:

```
<a href="waze://?ll=31.66526,34.58684&navigate=yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

Waze has an API http://www.waze.com/dev/documentation/

Please look at the code there. It shows a regular a href="" but it is related to longitude and lattitude you need to get from google maps or something else.

```
<a href="waze://?ll=31.66526,34.58684&navigate=yes"><img src="wazeimage.jpg"></a>
```

if you copy the long/lat and paste in google maps it shows a cafe in israel somewhere: 31.66526,34.58684

Comment: and where do I need to put the API ?

Comment: You don't "put" the api anywhere. You take the basic link above, change the longitude and latitude and voila!    For example, I went to gmaps, and got a link: https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=34.134075,-118.321912       paste 34.134075,-118.321912 in to google and see what happens!

Comment: I pasted this code in my mobile site, it opens Waze but dont mark the  longitude and latitude (destination), look at this http://www.easy-time.info/mobile/pg3.php

Comment: if you are using wordpress, there is a great plugin which allows you to do it, take a look here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-waze/